# Processes with communication exclusive from the OS

Tags: operating-systems, applications, message-passing

Most OSes use the message passing system to let 2 processes communicated with each other.This works by a shared mailbox between the OS and each process loaded in the RAM however are there processes which have their own shared mailbox and can communicate without the OS acting as a middleman?

Answer (score 2):

Two isolated processes need some OS support for passing messages between each other, but there need not be a system call for every message.

One simple way is to use virtual memory. You could, for example, use [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) or a [memory-mapped file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) to share a piece of memory between two processes, and communication can then proceed using shared data structures for communication.

Many operating systems also provide cross-process [synchronisation](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/%7Emdamian/threads/posixsem.html) [objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/interprocess-synchronization) if waiting is needed.